# Bulk upload with csv for downloadable products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can anyone please tell me how to implement bulk uploading through .csv for downloadable products. I have tried for simple products but failed for downloadable products. Need Help

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? Can I presume you're using dataflow?

Answer (score 0):

I use this module from Commerce Extensions, makes it really easy to bulk upload loads of downloadable tracks and even add the downloadable LINKS too, was only $99 and the support was really good - http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-product-import-export.html

Answer (score -1):

Default, you can't export and import full attribute product downloadable, configurable, grouped, bundle. You should use some extension for your work.

Try use one http://www.mlx-store.com/magento-extensions/import-export/export-import-bulk-product-with-configurable-product-bundle-product-grouped-product-downloadable-product-tier-price-group-price-related-products-up-sells-cross-sells-product-tags-magento.html

Comment: Provide ome minimal info on what you are exactly referencing in your answer.